# FTP connection from a computer using Android as a router

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, android, filezilla

I can't connect to an external server using Filezilla when I use my Android phone as a router. It works when connected to a "normal" router. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What do you mean connect **to** Filezilla? Filezilla is not a server, it is an application? Do you perhaps mean to an FTP server? Can you please give more details in your question, like the topology, scenario, what exactly are you trying to do, etc.

Comment: Reworded. I hope it's easier to understand now. Thanks!

Comment: Can you ping that server while you're using your phone as a router?

Comment: Yes, the connection was initiated but the user and password is not sent.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, the user and the password are not sent and that's why the connection is not completely established.
Not really a solution to the problem I post, but I tried with a different server and it worked perfectly, so I tried to connect to the first server using Nautilus instead of Filezilla and it also worked, so this is the solution I am using. Thank you for your time!